# Memory error using scipy.fftpack, how to avoid it?

Tags: python, memory, numpy, scipy, fft

I need to compute Fourier coefficients in Python from a .tiff medical image. The code produces a memory error:

```
for filename in glob.iglob ('*.tif'):
        imgfourier = scipy.misc.imread (filename, flatten = True)
        image = numpy.array([imgfourier])#make an array 
         # Take the fourier transform of the image.
        F1 = fftpack.fft2(image)
         # Now shift so that low spatial frequencies are in the center.
        F2 = fftpack.fftshift(F1)
         # the 2D power spectrum is:
        psd2D = np.abs(F2)**2
        print psd2D
```

Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks

Comment: How big is your image, and how much memory do you have?

Answer (score 2):

I found [this discussion](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.scientific.devel/16250) where they identified memory leaks in `scipy.fftpack`, suggesting to use `numpy.fft` package instead. Also, you can save memory avoiding the intermediate variables:

```
import numpy as np
import glob
import scipy.misc
for filename in glob.iglob('*.tif'):
    imgfourier = scipy.misc.imread (filename, flatten = True)
    print np.abs(np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(np.array([imgfourier]))))**2
```

Comment: File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\fft\fftpack.py", line 75, in _raw_fft
    r = work_function(a, wsave)
MemoryError